How to send a signal to a set of pthread within one process in Linux?
I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24).
There is a multi-threaded process needed to handle a certain of exception delivered through a signal.
The process is something like below.
void *thread2(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        does_other_jobs();
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *thread1(void *arg)
{
    pthread_create(tid2, ..., thread2, ...);

    while(1) {
        does_some_job();
    }
    pthread_join(...);

    return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    pthread_create(tid1, ..., thread1, ...);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
}

Now, I want to have a way to kill/stop running of thread1 and its children.
I tried to send SIGTERM to thread1, but the SIGTERM killed this process as a whole. What I did is as follows,
int main()
{
    sigset_t mask;

    pthread_create(tid1, ..., thread1, ...);

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGTERM);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);

    return 0;
}

So is there anyting wrong in above implementation? And is there a way to only stop running of thread1 and its children pthread?

Here's one possible solution:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct {
    int pipe_fds[2];
    pthread_mutex_t running_mutex;
    bool running;
} ThreadState;

typedef struct {
    bool keep_running;
} AbortMessage;

static bool should_keep_running(ThreadState *state)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&state->running_mutex);

    // Some other thread has received a message over the pipe from the
    // signal handler indicating that it's time to stop.
    if (!state->running) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&state->running_mutex);
        return false;
    }

    AbortMessage msg = {
        .keep_running = true,
    };

    // Try to read any message that the signal handler may have sent
    // indicating that it's time to stop processing.  Since we marked this
    // file descriptor as non-blocking, this read() won't block if there's
    // no message (it won't return a positive value in that case).
    const int bytesRead = read(state->pipe_fds[0], &msg, sizeof(msg));

    if (bytesRead != sizeof(msg))
    {
        // We didn't receive any message.  This thread should keep going.
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&state->running_mutex);
        printf("No msg received on pipe, keep going\n");
        return true;
    }

    printf("Msg received on pipe\n");

    // Record the state for other threads that might be interested.
    state->running = msg.keep_running;

    const bool running = state->running;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&state->running_mutex);

    return running;
}

static void does_some_job(void) { sleep(3); }
static void does_other_jobs(void) { sleep(5); }

static void *thread2(void *arg)
{
    ThreadState *state = arg;

    while (should_keep_running(state)) {
        does_other_jobs();
    }

    printf("Thread 2 terminating\n");

    return NULL;
}

static void *thread1(void *arg)
{
    ThreadState *state = arg;

    pthread_t t2;
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, thread2, state);

    while (should_keep_running(state)) {
        does_some_job();
    }

    pthread_join(t2, NULL);

    printf("Thread 1 terminating\n");

    return NULL;
}

static ThreadState thread_state = {
    .running_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    .running = true,
};

// signal handlers are _very_ limited in terms of what they can safely do.
// (see `man 7 signal-safety`).  One of the things they can safely so is
// call the `write()` system call.
//
// When this signal handler fires, it writes a message to a pipe.  Other
// threads periodically try to read the message, and terminate if received.
static void signal_handler(int)
{
#define PRINT_MSG(x) write(STDOUT_FILENO, x, sizeof(x))
    PRINT_MSG("signal received\n");
#undef PRINT_MSG

    const AbortMessage msg = {
        .keep_running = false,
    };

    write(thread_state.pipe_fds[1], &msg, sizeof(msg));
}

int main(void)
{
    const struct sigaction sa = {
        .sa_handler = signal_handler,
    };
    pthread_t t1;

    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    // Create a communication pipe over which the signal handler can
    // communicate with the rest of the program.
    pipe(thread_state.pipe_fds);

    // Make the read-end of the pipe non-blocking, so if there is no message
    // from the signal handler, a read() won't block waiting.
    fcntl(thread_state.pipe_fds[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(thread_state.pipe_fds[0], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    pthread_create(&t1,  NULL, thread1, &thread_state);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);

    return 0;
}

The inline comments describe the details, and I've omitted error checking for simplicity.  At a high level, this:

Creates a pipe that enables the signal handler to communicate safely with the rest of the program.
Updates the threads to periodically check the read-end of the pipe.  If they get a message, they record that for other threads and then terminate themselves (i.e., return from the thread-entry function).
If during the periodic check, a thread notices that some other thread has terminates (the running field has been set to false), then it also terminates.

Here's a sample run of this program:
$ ./a.out
No msg received on pipe, keep going
No msg received on pipe, keep going
No msg received on pipe, keep going
No msg received on pipe, keep going
No msg received on pipe, keep going
^Csignal received
Msg received on pipe
Thread 2 terminating
Thread 1 terminating
$

First, both threads are executing.  They periodically call should_keep_going(), and that prints No msg received on pipe, keep going.  That goes on for a while.
After some time, I press Ctrl-c (denoted by the ^C).
The signal handler received the signal and prints signal received.  The signal handler writes a message on the pipe.
After some time, some thread calls should_keep_going() again.  This time, it reads a message from the pipe and prints Msg received on pipe.  It records the state in the running field and returns false.
Some time later, the other thread calls should_keep_going() again.  This time, it noticed that some other thread had received a message over the pipe from the signal handler (the running field is false), so it returns false.
With both threads no longer executing their loops, thread2 has printed Thread 2 terminating and returned, allowing thread1()'s call to pthread_join() to complete and print Thread 1 terminating.  Finally, main()'s call to pthread_join() to finish, and it terminates.

Thank Andy for this detailed solution. I think using pipe as IPC is fine if both thread1 and thread2 are written by myself.  In other cases where the thread1 and thread2 are created by third-party codes like a blackbox, is there any other way to stop them in one shoot?

@wangt13 If you're using a library that has threading, then that library would need to expose some mechanism to enable you to tell them to stop.  As a general rule, you can't stop threads externally -- you don't know what state they're in, what resources they've allocated, and what they need to do to clean up.  Instead, you have to politely ask threads to stop themselves, then wait until they do.

I agreed with you on this. So I think the possible way to do that is to have this function as seperate process (thread group with multi threads), and kill them with an external signal?

It's hard to give you a concrete answer based on your abstract question, so this may or may not apply to your use case. If you fork() (create a new process), then start the threads in the new process, you could "stop" the threads by terminating that process.  If you depend on program state that is shared, that won't work since you won't share state with the child process.

I totally agreed with you Andy. And your comment give me confidence to build up a prototype to try this. Thank you.

While I don't want to preclude that you can build something around signals, it seems like a pretty bad idea to me: No guarantees whatsoever on execution order, no controlled error handling, stack unwinding, massive context switch overhead; this seems to me a very unclean approach which will lead to memory leaks, and depending on what data is exchanged between your threads, potentially incomplete / broken data. Not a way I'd recommend, at all.
Instead, you'd typically use condition variables, i.e. instead of while(1) (very C89, and this isn't 1989; use while(true), maybe ;))  you'd do something like acquiring a pthread mutex, and checking a variable being true still, then enter the loop, release the mutex, do the loop content, then acquire the mutex, before the loop condition is checked again.
Frankly, if you're learning how to write multi-threaded applications in 2024, I a) wouldn't know whether pthreads is where I start, and b) I'd not be sure whether C would be the beginner-friendly language of choice for these kinds of things. So many things that you need to handle yourself, which other programming languages have already solved in sensible ways for you!
If you really decide to stick with C and pthreads, read a sensible tutorial on that; the way you're using it feels like someone who's been programming for POSIX operating systems by spawning processes from 1985 to 1995 and now is supposed to learn this "newfangled thing" pthreads in 1995. Well, it's 30 years old, and you're probably not from that 80's C and POSIX background!
Have one thread (and that's usually the main thread) handle all signals (concurrently executed signal handlers are basically intractible in side effects, so you never want that), and all other threads communicate cooperatively.

The background of my doing this is there are foreign codes in the thread2 that I cannot control (blackbox), so I want to find a clean way to stop (and reclaim) these threads.  By reading https://mazzo.li/posts/stopping-linux-threads.html, I think I am maybe in the wrong way to do that. The right way might be running these foreign codes in a seperate process (multi-threaded), and stop their running by kill the whole process (TGID).
